# Split file into multiple when special char met

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I have a main file as following :

```
/* ------------- AAAAAAAA ------------- */
some
lines 
here
/* ------------- BBBBBBBB ------------- */
more
things
/* ------------- CCCCCCCC ------------- */
there
a 
few
more
lines
```

My final goal is to create a file that will containt only block that contains a specific string, for example if that string would be `lines` then I would have an output file like this :

```
/* ------------- AAAAAAAA ------------- */
some
lines 
here
/* ------------- CCCCCCCC ------------- */
there
a 
few
more 
lines
```

To reach my objective, I first try to split my main file into subfiles by bock to get something like

- file-1
- file-2
- file-3

Then I plan to check each file and if then contains the searched string then I append them back to my new main file.

I don't know if it's the best approach to be honest, moreover that I got more than 1600 blocks for 30139 lines in my main file so that's a lot to parse.

However if I keep this way to do the job, I still have an issue with my code :

```
#!/bin/ksh
i=0
while IFS=\| read -r "line"; do
        if [ `echo $line | grep '/* ------' | wc -l` -eq 1 ]; then
                i=$((i+1))
        fi
        echo $line > "file-$i"
done < $1
```

As each block are separated by `/* --------`, if I do an `echo $line`, the output will be my root directory (`/etc`, `/tmp` etc) and not the `$line` itself.

So I'm aware that this is a 2 questions-post but because the second problem can be bypassed using a different way doing the script, it is definitely linked.

**EDIT :**

The solution has to be in korn shell as I cannot install anything on this machine

Comment: please add: *the solution has to be in korn shell* in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you really want to use a `while read` construction, try avoiding additional files and system calls.

```
matched=0
all=
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ ${line} =~ "/* ----"* ]]; then
      if [ ${matched} -eq 1 ]; then
         printf "%s\n" "${all}"
      fi
      all=
      matched=0
  fi
  all="${all}${line}
"
  if [[ "${line}" =~ line ]]; then
    matched=1
  fi
done < <(cat mainfile; echo "/* ---- The End --- */" )
```

Answer (score 2):

Another one in awk:

```
$ awk '
function dump() {         # define a function to avoid duplicate code in END
    if(b~/lines/)         # if buffer has "lines" in it
        print b           # output and ...
    b="" }                # reset buffer
/^\/\*/ { dump() }        # at the start of a new block dump existing buffer
{ b=b (b==""?"":ORS) $0 } # gather buffer
END{ dump() }             # dump the last buffer also
' file
/* ------------- AAAAAAAA ------------- */
some
lines 
here
/* ------------- CCCCCCCC ------------- */
there
a 
few
more
lines
```

Comment: the solution has to be in korn shell

Comment: OK, sorry about that. That should be stated that in the OP as it was tagged shell and linux along with the ksh.

Answer (score 1):

if you do not mind using **Perl** then there is a good **one-liner** that makes your achievement easy.

The only thing you need is add a line like this:

```
/* ------------- END ------------- */
```

at the very end of your file. so that become this:

```
/* ------------- AAAAAAAA ------------- */
some
lines 
here
/* ------------- BBBBBBBB ------------- */
more
things
/* ------------- CCCCCCCC ------------- */
there
a 
few
more
lines
/* ------------- END ------------- */
```

Now with the help of this [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) pattern :

### `\/\*.*?(?=\/\*)`

you can match each part separately. For example this part:

```
/* ------------- AAAAAAAA ------------- */
some
lines 
here
```

Thus, if your store the result in an **array** at the end you would have an array that contains **3** section. And eventually your can apply for `lines` in each section. If it was found, then that section would be printed.

**one-liner**

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/=undef;}push(@arr,$&) while/\/\*.*?(?=\/\*)/smg;END{for (@arr){print if /lines/g }}' file
```

and the output would be:

```
/* ------------- AAAAAAAA ------------- */
some
lines 
here
/* ------------- CCCCCCCC ------------- */
there
a 
few
more
lines
```

and if you apply for `more`:

```
/* ------------- BBBBBBBB ------------- */
more
things
/* ------------- CCCCCCCC ------------- */
there
a 
few
more
lines
```

---

*based on @batMan solution*

**command line solution:**

```
tr '\n' ';' < file | grep -Po '\/\*.*?(?=\/\*)' | grep lines | tr ';' '\n'
```

its output:

```
/* ------------- AAAAAAAA ------------- */
some
lines 
here

/* ------------- CCCCCCCC ------------- */
there
a 
few
more
lines
```

Comment: That is a pretty nice solution but I unfortunately can't use Perl; it has to be in korn shell :/

Comment: okay. follow the technique that I have gone. First read the entire file. Then split it into three section by applying an appropriate pattern. And at the end you have 3 separate sections. Then you can apply your string: `lines` or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

using **awk**

```
awk -v RS="/[*]" '/lines/{printf "/*"$0}' file
```

Output:

```
/* ------------- AAAAAAAA ------------- */
some
lines
here
/* ------------- CCCCCCCC ------------- */
there
a
few
more
lines
```

Comment: Oh based on your `tr` I created a command-line solution. thank you :)

Comment: Welcome !! BTW I've removed the `tr` and updated the solution using only `awk` as using `tr` needs to invoke multiple pipes and degrades the performance. Avoid this. Check the updated one :)